# How to make Angular2 App faster

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

Actually I add these js files to start my Angular 2 app:-

[image]

But my page is loading around 400 Http calls, which is making app a bit slower.
out of these 400 calls 200 calls are initiating from system.js, please see in this pic [image]

Is there a way to make it faster ??

Comment: this is not a duplicate question man, read it again before marking

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the minimized version of the file and use a CDN for delivery.